# Creating JSON in Windows 8 C# using IJsonValue: Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Windows.Data.Json.IJsonValue'

Tags: c#, json, windows-8

I am creating a Windows 8 App in C# using Visual Studio. I am trying to take a bunch of data input and create a JSON object from that data. Here is my preliminary test method that does not work:

```
        IJsonValue name = "Alex"; 
        JsonObject Character = new JsonObject();
        Character.Add("Name", name);
```

The error that I am getting is

```
Cannot Implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Windows.Data.Json.IJsonValue'
```

I looked up the documentation for IJsonValue but couldn't figure out how to create an instance of IJsonValue containing a string. So how do I store data in an IJsonValue to be added to a JsonObject?

Comment: `IJsonValue` is an interface, not a class (hence the "I" as prefix). The only thing you can assign to `IJsonValue name` is an object whose class implements the `IJsonValue` interface.

Comment: If your data is in a class, probably the easiest way to convert it to JSON would be to use the Newtonsoft JSON.NET library and call SerializeObject with your class instance... example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345382/convert-object-to-json-string-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Sandra, I used the Newtonsoft library, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how you would do it:

```
JsonObject character = new JsonObject();
character.Add("Name",JsonValue.CreateStringValue("Alex"));
```

Answer (score 3):

The class [JsonValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.jsonvalue.aspx) implements the IJsonValue interface.  You can create an instance of the class and use it like this for example ...

```
JsonValue jsonValue = JsonValue.Parse("{\"Width\": 800, \"Height\": 600, \"Title\": \"View from 15th Floor\", \"IDs\": [116, 943, 234, 38793]}");
double width = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedNumber("Width");
double height = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedNumber("Height");
string title = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedString("Title");
JsonArray ids = jsonValue.GetObject().GetNamedArray("IDs");
```

[Check out this for more examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh770289.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that handling JSON in this manner (almost like xpath) is a little brittle because there is little opportunity for typing and compile-time checks. Deserializing JSON into a strongly typed class is a more long-term and reliable approach that also gives you easier interaction with the data. It doesn't mean this `GetNamedString` approach does not work, it does. It's just a more typed and controlled approach that easier to use and less likely to break. :) Here's some info on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965829/how-do-i-de-serialize-json-in-winrt