# Send List<Type> over tcp in metro app

Tags: c#, windows-8, tcp, windows-runtime

I am making a metro multiplayer game.

I have a list `List<Card> Cards = new List<Card>();` with my custom class "Card"

Is there any way to send this list over StreamSocket?

I have search google but i cant find any info about sending list object.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the object and then deserialize on the other end, and there are a few options for doing so.

Here's [one article from Iris Classon using DataContractSerializer](http://www.irisclasson.com/2012/07/09/example-metro-app-winrt-serializing-and-deseralizing-objects-to-storagefile-and-localfolder-using-generics-and-asyncawait-threading/)

and another [post from Jerry Nixon leveraging DataContractJsonSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965829/how-do-i-de-serialize-json-in-winrt), with another answer referencing how to do it with JSON.NET.